# Change SOLR Default Conjunction

Tags: search, solr, lucene

I'm using an app that has SOLR embedded.
SOLR is running as a war in the webapps area of Tomcat.
Is there a SOLR configuration that allows me to switch the default SOLR behavior for searches to assume 'AND' instead of 'OR' as the conjunctive operator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add (or modify h/t @Madbreaks ) this line in your schema file (usually `schema.xml`)

```
<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="AND"/>
```

Comment: It's deprecated so you should set the q.op parameter in your request handler configuration in solrconfig.xml instead of using the default operator from schema.xml.