# Why does SOLR miss a very clear match when using the word 'in'?

Tags: solr

We have SOLR indexing a knowledge-base database.

Searching for the following phrase does not return ANY results:

```
unknown exception thrown in worker
```

While searching for any of the phrases below does provide the expected match:

```
"unknown exception thrown in worker"
unknown exception thrown worker
```

Trying out a few other terms I identified the following words caused this behavior:

```
 in
 for
 of
```

**What I already know:**

It is not strictly 2 or 3 letter words, because some 3 letter words I tried did not affect the search in this way (did not compute into the search either, but at least didn't DUMP it)

**The Question**

Any idea what is going on? 
or 
Any suggestions where should I look to better understand what is going on?

Comment: What is the definition of the fields you're searching in? Are you just removing stopwords on index and not on query, and require all terms to be present?

Comment: It could be that your default operator is the conjunction. Make sure it is not, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10592475/3229995

Comment: We would require your schema.xml, at least the portion that describes the text analysis of that field you are searching in, the configuration of the queryHandler you are using out of the solrconfig.xml and the parameters you are using to make the request, as you may override defaults with the request.

Comment: Thank all, I'll try and figure it out, and if I'm stuck I'll upload the content as described by @cheffe.